# Dynamic Thymeleaf fragment location

Tags: thymeleaf

Imagine a tag:

```
<div th:replace="pageName/page.html :: fragmentName" />
```

where `pageName` should come from model like `${page.name}`, but I don't know the syntax how I can insert a variable to the beginning of the fragment location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451), you can simply use variables in fragment expressions.  (The example given is `~{${templateName} :: ${fragmentName}}`.  This should work for you:

```
<div th:replace="~{|pageName/${page.name}.html| :: fragmentName}" />
```